# How to set a variable from a single form input value

Tags: php, arrays, forms

If I have two input forms such as...

```
    <input type="text" class="foo2" name="bar1" id="someid1" value="" />
    <input type="text" class="foo2" name="bar2" id="someid2" value="" />

<Some Javascript to get the variable from "bar1">
< Some PHP to set a php variable based on the previous javascript variable >

result --- $phpvariable = (the user defined variable in name="bar1")
```

And in the same file wanted to set the "value" from the first form to a php variable, what would be some ways I could accomplish that?

Edit.. Since the value is empty, the user inputs the value and a php variable is set before the form is submitted.  I'm assuming javascript would need to be used along with json_encode, but I'm not familiar enough with Javascript to do accomplish this.

Comment: `value="<?php echo $some_value; ?>"`

Comment: But I have no idea what the value is before the user enters it.  I'll update the question.

Comment: In PHP handler, `$bar1=$_POST['bar1']; echo $bar1;` etc.

Comment: I need this to be done 'before' the form is submitted.

Comment: Then you need an event listener.

Comment: Could you provide a sample to help me understand?

Comment: Sorry, I suggest you Google that term (above) along with Ajax. I for one do not provide code, including many others here. You need to provide code (what you tried) and tell us where you are having difficulties with, in particular. What you posted is not enough, unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

You need to ajax (see http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) to your .php page.

Say you have a php file called ajaxMe.php with the contents:

```
<?php
    echo $_REQUEST['passedVariable'] . "!";
?>
```

Now if you ajax to the url: ajaxMe.php?passedVariable=Hello, the response will be "Hello!"

Comment: I'm trying to get the users input and using JavaScript create a variable from that value.  I realize php is server, and javascript is client-side.  What I'm needing to do is client-side so javascript is the tool... but after that's done and the javascript variable is set, I need to change that variable to PHP.  Can json_encode do that on the same instance of the page?

Comment: So your asking how to submit form data so you can handle it with php?

Comment: No, I've updated the question again to explain what I'm after.